# Regular expression search for multiple files with summary for Regex groups

Tags: windows, gratis, programming, text-processing, file-search

I have a lot of files to search (17000+). I would like to search the file content using a regular expression. Unlike all programs that I know until now, I don't want to get a list of files (there will be 635 for my current search) and review each individual file.

Instead, I want to get a summary and a statistics for all the occurrences.

Example:

Search term: `#pragma warning\(disable(.*)\)`

Result:

```
4996                   122 hits
4290                    18 hits
4049                     7 hits
4127                    88 hits
4987 4820 4987 4820      1 hit
```

I have tried:

- [Agent Ransack / FileLocator Lite](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/), which does a good job and is fast and provides a summary, but unluckily just about the number of hits *per file*, which I don't need in this scenario.
- [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) is searching for file names, not file content.

I like this on Windows and not pay for it (gratis, open source preferred).

Comment: Does https://www.voidtools.com/ fit the bill? It appears to have a regex capability; I haven't tried it.

Comment: @BillBell: Search Everything searches for the file name only, not the file content.

Comment: I didn't think to mention https://alternativeto.net/software/agent-ransack/ before.